# SQL if value null write x

Tags: mysql, sql

I need an SQL sentence that allows me to write the variable called "target" but if there is any null value there write the content of "target2". For now I have this.

```
SELECT TRIM(b.C1) AS TARGET, 
       TRIM(b.C2) AS TARGET2       
FROM "nameOfFile1.csv" a
LEFT JOIN "nameOfFile2.csv" b ON a.JBF_DSC_JOB_FUNC=b.JOB_FUNCTION_DSC
 WHERE TRIM(a.JBF_DSC_JOB_FUNC)='$(identity)'
```

I dont know how to add something like `if (target = null) then  write target2`

Thanks in advice!

Comment: Which RDMS MySQL is not Oracle database (where the oracle tag is about on this website)..  But MySQL is owned by Oracle Corporation.

Comment: @Lewis . .. Your query doesn't full make sense.  You are only selecting values from the *second* table.  Because you are using a `LEFT JOIN`, both may be `NULL`.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff and whats your advice? :S

Comment: @Lewis . . . I'm just pointing out that the question doesn't make sense.  You haven't provide sample data, desired results, or a full explanation of the logic.  What looks like the likely culprit for `NULL` values -- the outer join -- is not going to be addressed by anything (currently) in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`COALESCE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```
SELECT COALESCE(TRIM(b.C1), TRIM(b.C2)) AS RESULT       
FROM "nameOfFile1.csv" a
LEFT JOIN "nameOfFile2.csv" b ON a.JBF_DSC_JOB_FUNC=b.JOB_FUNCTION_DSC
WHERE TRIM(a.JBF_DSC_JOB_FUNC)='$(identity)'
```